# Tkinter-Dynamic available selections on radio button

Tags: python, shell, user-interface, tkinter

I have a requirement where I need to populate a list in the GUI after running a progrom. The following GUI is used to restore backups for a system.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(1)  # initializing the choice, i.e. Python

backups = [
    (200,"WIN_7", "active", 4096, 320, 1),
    (201,"WIN_7_sp1", "active", 4096, 320, 2),
    (210,"WIN_Java", "inactive", 8019, 8),
    (230,"Linux_C78", "active", 4096, 90),
    (241,"Linux2_B78", "active", 4096, 80)
]

def ShowChoice():
    print(v.get())

tk.Label(root,
         text="""Choose a backup
to restore from the list:""",
         justify = tk.LEFT,
         padx = 20).pack()

for val, backup in enumerate(backups):
    tk.Radiobutton(root,
                  text=backup,
                  padx = 20,
                  variable=v,
                  command=ShowChoice,
                  value=val).pack(anchor=tk.W)


root.mainloop()
```

Since the backup list is changing from one system to another, the script needs to be changed to display the available backups after running the program 'listbk'. If I run the program 'listbk', it outputs the available backups as follows:

```
ID      NAME           STATUS      MEM    Disk    RANDOMID
100     WIN_7          active      4096     320        1
301      WIN_7_sp1     active      4096     320        2
390      WIN_Java      inactive    8019     320        8
480      Linux_C78     active      4096     320       90
541      Linux2_B78    active      4096     500       80
```

Inside the python script, I am able to run the script using the below command to get the backup list.

```
from subprocess import call
call(['listbk'])
```

What is the way to display the available backups for different systems in the GUI.

Thank you for your help...

Comment: I don't understand what you actually require assistance with here? You're running another command in another script and need some way of converting the output of that script into a tkinter GUI? How does this relate to the list of checkboxes you've already produced?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear...
I trying to find a way to update the list below:
backups = [
    (200,"WIN_7", "active", 4096, 320, 1),
    (201,"WIN_7_sp1", "active", 4096, 320, 2),
    (210,"WIN_Java", "inactive", 8019, 8),
    (230,"Linux_C78", "active", 4096, 90),
    (241,"Linux2_B78", "active", 4096, 80)
]

because everytime the 'listbk' runs the radiobutton should be updated. Because the backup list changes from system to system.

Thank you for your quick prompts.

Comment: Also, I am NOT running listbk command in another script. I run the command in the same script. I am trying to find a way to get the output of listbk to update the list "backups" and then radiobutton displays the output 
Thanks

Comment: If you're running it in the same script then you haven't shown that, can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example which includes ALL of the code necessary to produce what you are seeing.

Comment: Please provide `repr(call['listbk'])` for all systems you have access to. I don't think there'll be much shortcut so much to filter based on system id.